# Is the Divine Substance rational?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, persons-of-the-trinity

According to the answers [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5792/when-talking-about-the-trinity-what-does-persons-mean) and [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53160/what-is-the-difference-between-person-and-substance), the term *person* means "an individual substance of a rational nature".

According to trinitarian theology, the triune god exists as three consubstantial *persons* consisting of one *substance*.

Does this mean the triune god exists as three individual substances of a rational nature, consisting of one substance of an irrational nature, in which neither nature is divided so that each are fully rational and irrational?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Divine Substance (a.k.a. God) is supremely rational, as long as we understand the term *rational* to mean “capable of intellectual knowledge.”

As I mentioned in my [answer to the O.P.’s question regarding *person* and *substance*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53160/what-is-the-difference-between-person-and-substance), the Divine Substance (God) is perfectly identical with each one of the Persons.

The Persons are really distinct from one another, because they consist of the very relations of origin that subsist in the Godhead. However, there is *no* real distinction between Person and Substance. (In God, individual and universal substance coincide perfectly.)

(It is important to recall that the notions of *person* and *substance*—which strictly speaking apply only to creatures—are applied very improperly to God. That is why theses affirmation sound strange to us.)

As I mentioned in my previous [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53160/what-is-the-difference-between-person-and-substance), *substance* can have two slightly different connotations. For an Aristotelian like me, “substance” *primarily* means individual, concrete beings, like trees, flowers, stones, and human beings. *Secondarily* it can mean the common or universal *kind* of thing something is: for instance, tree-kind, flower-kind, stone-kind, and mankind. (For a Platonist, the priority is reversed—but for our purposes the fundamental idea is the same.) Also, “substance,” “essence,” and “nature” are basically synonyms for the ancient Greeks.

Now, Boethius’ definition for *person*, as the O.P. correctly mentions, is “individual substance with a rational nature.” We are, therefore, dealing with the two meanings of *substance* that I just mentioned above. Boethius is affirming, in effect, that a person is a *concrete being* that belongs to a particular *genus* or *kind* of being: namely those with the capacity for intellectual (rational) knowledge.

Boethius’ definition, as I mentioned, applies properly to creatures. God is beyond creaturely genera and species. However, He does possess to an infinite degree the capacity for intellectual knowledge (i.e., He is omniscient).

Therefore, both the Divine Nature or Substance (a.k.a. God) and the Divine Persons (who are, as I have mentioned, each perfectly identical to the Divine Nature) are not only rational but *supremely* rational.*

Hence, irrationality has no part whatsoever in God. Moreover, God is one Substance: the Persons do not divide the one Substance in any way whatsoever. In no way can He be considered three Substances.

---

* Note that in classical Scholastic lingo the term “rational” can be taken in a strict sense and in a broad sense. In the strict sense, “reason” and “rationality” refer to the particular kind of intellectual knowledge that we human beings possess. Our intellects are discursive; that is, we have to use concepts, enunciations, and argumentations to arrive at knowledge. Not all intellects are like that, however. For instance, angelic intellects are intuitive. In the *broad* sense, however, “rational” is a synonym for “intellectual.” That is what Boethius means by it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought this might mean the triune god is the fourth person of the triune god, but now I'm really confused. It seems like words are being used, only to be told that these words do not apply to the triune god, but then the words continue to be used as though they are still relevant. When you say "However, there is no real distinction between Person and Substance" this sounds like Sabellianism to me. Now I'm interested to know how [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53211/did-the-father-and-holy-spirit-become-man) will be answered.

Comment: The terms are applied analogically—which is to say, substance and person in God bear some resemblance to those realites among creatures (i.e., inasmuch as God is the Creator and Exemplar of those realities in creation). Saying that the Substance is a fourth entity in God is the heresy of [Gilbert de la Porrée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_de_la_Porr%C3%A9e). Sabellianism would say that there is no distinction among the Persons. The orthodox position is to say that Nature and Person are perfectly identical, but the Persons are really distinct.

Comment: I don't know. If I use these terms improperly like trinitarians do, but still act as though they are relevant, then it seems we have one rational substance (god), existing as three distinct rational substances which are all fully the one rational substance (person/mode), and the only difference between the three is their "relation of origin". Relation of origin sounds like a fancy phrase for "role".

Comment: Perhaps there is a better word than "person" that could help me understand how [god, god, and god](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53195/if-we-say-god-the-father-god-the-son-and-god-the-holy-spirit-can-we-say-god) are related.

Comment: @anonymouswho It might help to recall that the Persons are actually the relations of origin. The Father is Fatherhood; the Son is Generation, and the Spirit is Procession. A relation is not the “role” of the Person; it is His ontological condition. The Father is without origin, the Son receives the (complete and undivided) Divine Nature from the Father, and the Spirit receives the (complete and undivided) Divine Nature from the Father through the Son.

Comment: @anonymouswho Also, “improper” does not mean “irrelevant.” God is the creator of His creatures. So _person_ and _substance_ in creatures are a true reflection or manifestation of something that God has to an infinite degree in Himself. For instance, we affirm rightly that God is good. But the only goodness we have direct experience of is goodness among human beings. God is not good in precisely _that_ way; rather, He is infinitely _more_ good than any mere man could possibly be: so much so, that He would be better characterized as Goodness Itself.

Comment: Ok, based on these comments and Nathaniel's answer to "Did the Father and Holy Spirit become man?", I can definitely see the difference between modalism and trinitarianism. I still don't see a difference between trinitarianism and tritheism other than a play on words, but at least I've resolved this issue. I had gotten confused about this because of an answer I received [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53193/why-doesnt-the-father-have-additional-attributes-like-the-son-and-holy-spirit), but I probably just misunderstood.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by comparing "persons" with "goodness". If I say God is good, that is not improper; it's just an understatement. But if I say God is three individual, rational substances that each fully exists as one rational substance, that's not an understatement; it's incomprehensible.

Comment: @anonymouswho I mentioned goodness to illustrate how theology deals with God’s attributes. (Incidentally, I think it is easy to underestimate the immensity of God’s goodness in comparison to ours. But that is for another question.) As for Person and Substance, I think we may have confused things here. In God, there is no distinction between common and individual substance. We call Father, Son, and Holy Spirit “Persons” precisely because all of them are supremely _rational_, not because they are “individuals.” (However, like creaturely persons, they are the answer to the question _Who?_)

Comment: The problem here appears to be in the using of  the word  'substance'.  We are as humans unable to disassociate that word with something physical.  God is Spirit. Spirits have no substance. The best example of a Spirit I can think of is air. Air is made up of many varying things, all of which have differing characteristics, and yet have one common characteristic, that being so little physical mass as to be floating in the atmosphere; and though definite and separate they are all known as air.

Comment: @BYE There are spiritual substances; for example, angels. Air may help us to understand spirits, to some extent, but air is, in fact, entirely material. A “substance” is just something that exists separately, not an “accident.” They can be material or spiritual, or both (like us).